# Testing a session variable

Tags: django, session-variables, django-sessions

I came across Django `request.session`; I know how to set and test it for a **specific** value.

```
request.session['name'] = "dummy"
```

and somewhere I check

```
if request.session['name'] == "dummy" :
   #do something
```

But, now I have to check whether the session variable was even set in the first place? I mean how can I check whether there exists a value in the `request.session['name']` is set?

Is there a way to check it?

Comment: Python is case-sensitive. Django doesn't have `Request` or `Session`, it has `request.session`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`get` will do all the work for you. Check if the key exists, if not then the value is `None`

```
if request.session.get('name', None) == "dummy":
    print 'name is = dummy'
```

Comment: request.session.get('name') should  be enough

Comment: In many cases you will not know what the value in the session will be e.g. some tokens, login sessions etc. (this is regarding the way you equated it with a fixed string "dummy")

Answer (score 36):

Treat it as a Python dictionary:

```
if 'name' in request.session:
    print request.session['name']
```

How to use sessions: [Django documentation: How to use sessions](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/sessions/)

Comment: This is a much cleaner solution, compared to the accepted answer.

Comment: Related question. If I had another dictionary in the session variable e.g. {'b': {'z': 100}}, will I need to use multiple if statements? Assume that the variables may not exist (so in the previous example, 'b' and 'z' may not exist)

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing this is put it in `try`.

[In this the third example code snippet](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/sessions/#examples)

if you apply `del` operation in a `session` variable it which does not exist, so it throws `KeyError`.

so check it like this.

```
try:
    print(request.session['name'])
except KeyError:
    print('name variable is not set')
```